# Gradle - Can't access class fields

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am creating a gradle plugin in groovy, but I can't access the fields of the class. Here's what I have:

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
     project.extensions.create("myClass", MyClass)
     println project.myClass.getClass().getName()
     for(Field field : project.myClass.getClass().getFields()) {
        println field.getName()
        println field.getType()
     }
  }
}

class MyClass {
  @MyAnnotation("Hello world")
  String myFeild
}
```

Output

```
MyClass_Decorated
__$stMC
boolean
```

Expected

```
MyClass
myField
String
```

Comment: what is field in apply method? is MyClass inner class of MyPlugin?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I updated my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forget how groovy works... if you don't specify a scope on a field is it public?

`Class.getFields()` only returns the public fields in the class (and super classes). You might need to use a combination of `Class.getDeclaredFields()` and `Class.getSuperclass()` to get the private/protected/default scoped fields all the way up the class hierarchy.

If you don't want to reflect the `_Decorated` class, you can reference the class directly instead of using the instance.

Eg: `MyClass.fields` or `MyClass.declaredFields` in groovy

Or: `MyClass.class.getFields()` or `MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields()` in java

Answer (score 3):

```
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

greeting {

    message = 'Hi'
    greeter = 'Gradle'
}

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("greeting", GreetingPluginExtension)
        project.task('hello') << {
            println "${project.greeting.message} from ${project.greeting.greeter}"
        }
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {

    String message
    String greeter
}
```

Comment: hopefully this one help you

Comment: The example you provided does not show why the reflection did not work

Comment: go through this site, 
http://pkaq.github.io/gradledoc/docs/userguide/custom_plugins.html